# Google Closure equivalent of jQuery's ".on()"

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-closure-library

I'm working with a project in Google Closure, and I'd like to attach event listeners to query selectors so that they apply likewise to dynamically added elements. If I were using jQuery, I might do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.targetclass', function(e) {...});
```

I've been unable to find any documentation on a similar capability in the Google Closure library. I suppose such a thing could be easily built in which you can register handlers to some global list of handlers, but given how common this pattern is I'd be very surprised if I was not re-inventing the wheel.

Is there such a thing in Google Closure?

Comment: It's [goog.events.listen](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/events_tutorial)

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure I understand. goog.events.listen requires an element to attach the listener to, but I want the listener attached to the document and matched against a query selector (or similar) on trigger. If I set up a listener using goog.events.listen and *later* add a dom element which should also be affected by the listener, how does this know about the new element?

Comment: So you want **delegated** event handlers. The Closure Library is mainly for use with Google products, and doesn't support delegation, you'd have to roll your own in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following code that will provide you as a reference.

Usually, event handlers are put under the enterDocument function that is inherited from goog.ui.Component. targetEl_ is dyanamically added inside createDom() and the event handler is attached after it enters the DOM.

```
// sample.js    
goog.provide('my.page.Sample');


goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.ui.Component');

/**
 * @constructor
 * @returns {my.page.Sample}
 */
my.page.Sample = function() {
    goog.base(this);
    this.targetEl_ = null;
};
goog.inherits(my.page.Sample, goog.ui.Component);


/** 
 * Creates the DOM elements and appends to the element referred while calling render() in test.js
 * @inheritDoc
 */
my.page.Sample.prototype.createDom = function() {
    this.targetEl_ = goog.dom.createDom(goog.dom.TagName.DIV, {"class": "targetElClass"});
    this.setElementInternal(targetEl_); 
};

/** 
 * Called after the components elements are known to be in the document.
 * @inheritDoc
 */
my.page.Sample.prototype.enterDocument = function() {
    goog.base(this, 'enterDocument');
    goog.events.listen(this.targetEl_, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, this.handleClicked_, false, this);

};

/**
 * @private
 * @param  {Event} event
 */
my.page.Sample.prototype.handleClicked_ = function(event) {
    // Handle the event here.
};


// test.js

goog.provide('my.page.Test');

goog.require('my.page.Sample');
test.init = function(sel) {
    var el = document.querySelector(sel);
    var myPage = new my.page.Sample();
    myPage.render(el);
};
```